# Can't remove USB is write protect

Tags: usb, read-only, write-protect

I'm using a full 2GB USB. Now it is automatically write-protected. I can't delete, add file or format the USB. I always safely remove before removing it. I have tried both editing regedit and diskpart as instructions on the internet. I have also scan it with a trusted antivirus. Please help me. I'm thinking of a person blocking my USB for money :(. Thanks for your help.
P/s: the drive's type is currently FAT.

Comment: I don't think the USB is corrupted. I can still open the drive, see and open files

Comment: … which it the perfect definition of 'triggered the firmware write-protect mechanism'… which is irreversible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your USB's firmware has gone into write-protect mode automatically (for some reason). Short of buying a new USB and copying the files onto there, there's really now much you can do at this point. :(